# Фильтрация в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть страница с товарами, на ней фильтры, фильтры формируются в зависимости от того, какие атрибуты есть у товаров, и какие значения принимают эти атрибуты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким способом все это выводится на страницу:

```
    @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>{{ $attribute->title }}</label>
            @foreach($values as $value)
                @if($attribute->id==$value->attribute_id)
                    <br>
                    <input name="filter_{{$attribute->id}}[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $value->value }} ">
                    {{ $value->value }}
                    {{ $attribute->unit }}
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Метод контроллера:

```
public function show(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $products = $category->products();
    $attributes = Attribute::get();
    $values = DB::table('attribute_product')->select('value', 'attribute_id')->get();

    if($request->has('name'))
    {
        $products->where('title', 'like', "%$request->name%");

    }

    if($request->has('filter_1'))
    {
        $products->WhereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->whereIn('value', $request->filter_1)->where('attribute_id', 1);
        });
    }

    if($request->has('filter_2'))
    {
        $products->WhereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->whereIn('value', $request->filter_2)->where('attribute_id', 2);
        });
    }

    $products = $products->get();

    return view('category.show', [
        'attributes' => $attributes,
        'category' => $category,
        'products' => $products,
        'values' => $values
    ]);
}
```

При увеличении атрибутов, будет разрастаться данный метод, и каждое добавление нового атрибута товара повлечет за собой ручное редактирование кода контроллера.

Собственно вопрос: как скомпоновать все это в одну проверку, дабы это дело автоматизировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить тип передачи данных:

```
// Шаблон.
<input name="filter[{{$attribute->id}}][{{ $value->value }}]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

```
// Контроллер.
if ($request->has('filter')) {
  foreach ($request->filter as $key => $filter) {
    $products->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($key, $filter) {

      // array_keys($filter) - берем только ключи из массива,
      // потому что значения всегда `1`. Не отмеченных checkbox тут нет.
      $query->whereIn('value', array_keys($filter))->where('attribute_id', (int) $key);

    });
  }
}
```

Не забывайте про валидацию! Обратите внимание на написание `whereHas`.